# jQuery dialog related post

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery .dialog() in my code.
In dialog i am having Form. On ok button of dialog, i want to submit the form...but It is not submitting code on ok. I have written  tag in dialog. Am i writing something wrong

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
    <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

    <form id='form1' name='form1' action='next.php'>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        <label for="email">Email</label>

        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        OK: function() {
            //$( this ).dialog( "close" );
            $('#form1').submit();
            return true;
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
});
```

Comment: Does _delated_ stand for _delayed_? I can't rightly deduce..

Comment: it was mistake...i have changed it

Comment: That code looks fine to me - have you done any debugging?  Can you tell if the handler for the "OK" button is being called? Are there any JavaScript errors reported?

Comment: no java script errors ...i have done lot of debugging...if i write <form > out side this dialog box then it will submit the form

Comment: Is the "OK" handler ever invoked?

Comment: yes....on ok...it should submit the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer...
You cant put  tag in jQuery dialog.
You have to place it some where else on page, with required field hidden. And On submit,put all fields value from dialog to hidden box in form. then It will work

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your code and it appears to work fine for me.  The code posted in your question did have one typo -- do you have any javascript errors when you open the page?

```
$('#dialog-form').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 300,
  width: 350,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    OK: function() {
      //$(this).dialog('close');
      $('#form1').submit();
      return true;
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  },
  close: function() {
    allFields.val('').removeClass('ui-state-error');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your braces for the button declaration. It should look like this:

```
buttons: {
            OK: function() {
                    //$( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                         $('#form1').submit();
                                         return true;
                }
            ,
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
```

You were closing off the button declaration before the Cancel button was setup.

Update: it appears this has been fixed in the original post since I wrote this answer.

Comment: @Poonam - does the form still not submit with the corrected brackets?